# how to customize combobox with C#.NET to make the value I chose displays with different value

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
      public partical class Form1 : Form
      {
        public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();

          comboBox1.Items.Add("key1-value1");
          comboBox1.Items.Add("key2-value2");
          comboBox1.Items.Add("key3-value3");
        }
      }
    }
```

for example,the list is like this:
key1-value1
key2-value2
key3-value3
when I choose the third one, the value changes to value3
what I want is like this:https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx
but my project is a WinForm project
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your program. Is it web based (ASP.NET MVC, Razor) or is it a WinForms, WPF, UWP app? Can you provide some source code?

Comment: To further the above comment, could you share how you are populating the combo box so we can advise accordingly. You could do something on the SelectedIndexChanged event to manipulate the string, but there might be a better option.

Comment: it is just a C#.NET WinForm project,I dragged the comboBox from toolbox to the form

Comment: What you ask for seems like a bad UX practice. Why would the user's selection be altered? And what should be displayed when the user expands the dropdown again? Should key3-value3 appear as selected?

Comment: what I want is to get user's selection be altered.when the user expands the dropdown again "key1-value1" should be displayed. what I want is like this:https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx but my project is WinForm project

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode